# Crypt password with jQuery on beforeSybmit

Tags: javascript, jquery, md5

I have a problem to encrypt password before transmit with ajaxSubmit

## login_password is input password clear value

## login_password_md5 is input hidden

In my alert the password is crypted, so when i look a php file request i see it in clear

JavaScript / jQuery code :

```
var loginSubmit = function () {
    $(this).ajaxSubmit({
        
        beforeSubmit: function (p1, p2, p3, p4) {
            // Crypt 
            
            alert("cryptPassword");
            login_password_md5 = $().crypt( {
                method: 'md5',
                source: $('#login_password').val()
            });

            $("#login_password_md5").val(login_password_md5);
            passmd5 = $("#login_password_md5").val();
            alert(passmd5);

            $("#login_password").val("");
            
            var form = $("#form_login");
            
            // Validation
            $(form).validate(rulesLogin);
            if (!$(form).valid())
                return false;

            $("#btn_login").hide();
            $("#login_loader").show();

            return true;
        },
        success: function (p1, p2, p3, p4) {
            // Data JSon Correction
            var dataX = "";
            for(i in p1) {
                dataX += p1[i];
            } 

            var result = JSON.parse(dataX);
          
            //var result = p1;
            var xmlHttp = p2;
            var form = p4;                

            // Result is null
            if(result == null || result == "") {
                $("#login_loader").hide();
                $("#btn_login").show();
                $("#login_password").val("");
                $("#login_email").val("");
                alert("(ERROR-LOGIN-1000) : Result is NULL !");
                return false;
            }

            // Success is false OR exception is true
            if(result.success != true || result.exception != false || result.status != 0) {
                $("#login_loader").hide();
                $("#btn_login").show();
                $("#login_password").val("");
                $("#login_email").val("");
                alert("(ERROR-LOGIN-1001-" + result.status + ") : " + result.message);
                return false;
            }
            
            // AccessLevel : Suspended account
            if(result.data.AccessLevel == 10) {
                $("#login_loader").hide();
                $("#btn_login").show();
                $("#login_password").val("");
                $("#login_email").val("");
                alert("(ERROR-LOGIN-1002) : Your account has been suspended by an Administrator ! You can contact customer service using the Contact link at the bottom of this page.");
                return false;                
            }
            
            // AccessLevel : User deleted account
            if(result.data.AccessLevel == 20) {
                $("#login_loader").hide();
                $("#btn_login").show();
                $("#login_password").val("");
                $("#login_email").val("");
                alert("(ERROR-LOGIN-1003) : You deleted your account. You can contact customer service using the Contact link at the bottom of this page.");
                return false;                
            } else if (result.data.AccessLevel >= 30) {      
                
                top.location.href="/site";
            } else {
                $("#login_loader").hide();
                $("#btn_login").show();
                $("#login_password").val("");
                $("#login_email").val("");
                alert("(ERROR-LOGIN-1004) : AccessLevel error ! Please try again.");
                return false;                
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
};
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Can you explain better? You want to encrypt in some way (md5 or similar) a value (password) before sending through ajax?

Comment: Yes is exact i try to encrypt password before sending. The alert(passmd5) show the crypted password or, when i look into Firebug the value of hidden input ##login_password_md5 is null

Comment: Another info before trying to answer, you need to set the encrypted password value on an hidden field for some "external" logic or you just need to pass it along with other form data?

Comment: if you have a solution to pass it crypted without use an hidden input go for it, i use it just to try debug because i don't undestand why the $("#login_password_md5").val(login_password_md5) not really assign crypted password beforeSubmit. Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't test why the hidden text value doesn't get set with the encrypted password, but made a simple snippet working for me:

```
$("form").ajaxForm({
    beforeSubmit: function(data) {
        $(data).each(function(i, field) {
            if(field.name == "password") {
                var encrypted = $().crypt({
                    method: "md5",
                    source: field.value
                });

                field.value = encrypted;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
});
```

Actually, "beforeSubmit" allows you to block / modify form data before submitting. Returning false stops the submission, returning true makes the call continue. You can intercept and modify data at will. Note that you MUST set "name" attribute on submitted fields or they won't be available inside "data" passed to "beforeSubmit".

Made a small demo (posting to Google won't work, but take a look at the http call inside the inspector to see encrypted value getting correctly posted): http://jsfiddle.net/8B9fL/

Hope this helps.